# Spinner within gridpane has strange resize effects

Tags: javafx, resize, focus, spinner, gridpane

My goal is to have a GridPane where every item is grown to its max size. When I use the Spinner component, however, there are some unexplainable resize effects: whenever the Spinner component gets focus, or the value changes, it grows a bit, until the other component is on its minimum size.

Code snippet:

```
ChoiceBox<String> box1 = new ChoiceBox<>();
box1.getItems().add("Item 1");
box1.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

Spinner spinner = new Spinner(1, 365, 1);
spinner.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
gridPane.setHgap(5);
gridPane.setVgap(5);
gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(5));
gridPane.addRow(0, box1, spinner);

GridPane.setHgrow(box1, Priority.ALWAYS);
GridPane.setHgrow(spinner, Priority.ALWAYS);

Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 1000, 400);
primaryStage.setTitle("Spinner in GridPane");
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

Can anyone explain me why this is happening and how I can get rid of it?

Comment: This is a bug. Can you report a bug at [JDK Bug System](http://bugreport.java.com/) ?

Comment: I've reported it and it has already been marked as bug [JDK-8140507](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8140507)

Answer (score 0):

According to the JDKBug, it is fixed and going to be available in JAVA9